# checking for 'null' slots in a object array

Tags: c++

Hi there
I have come form the java camp and am trying to do a c++ program

I have an array called Manifest that takes passenger objects

```
for (int i = 0; i< _totalSeats; i++) 
{
    if (Manifest[i] != instanceOf Passenger) {
        cout<<"empty"endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<< PassengerToString(i);
    }
}
```

obviously the 'instanceOf' is a problem in C++, 
I know is==null doesn't work as there is no such thing as null without being specificly inserted
but to build a blank passenger objects then insert them in each array slot sounds messy and costly.
Is there a more elegent way?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're mapping seats to passengers. This means a `map` may be a better choice, such as `std::map<int, Passenger> Manifest`.

for example

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Passenger
{
        public:
                std::string toString() const
                {
                        return "Passenger";
                }
};

int main()
{
        std::map<int, Passenger> Manifest;
        Manifest[2] = Passenger();
        int _totalSeats = 10;

         for (int i = 0; i< _totalSeats; i++)
         {
             if (Manifest.count(i))
                     std::cout << Manifest[i].toString() << '\n';
             else
                     std::cout << "empty\n";
         }
}
```

test run:   https://ideone.com/XkNOg

Answer (score 1):

You can't really create an array of objects in C++ *without* constructing them all (well, actually, you *can*, but it's ugly, black magic stuff.) Don't use arrays -- use std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way, would be to only store objects that are valid in the container.  So, instead of using a fixed-size array, you can use a `std::vector<Passenger>` and add and remove `Passenger`s to it as needed.

If the position of the `Passenger` objects is important (i.e., the index is important), you can easily use a `std::map<int, Passenger>`.

Otherwise, there are numerous approaches to solve the problem:

- Use a container of smart pointers (for example, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Passenger>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Passenger> >`) or a pointer container (for example, `boost::ptr_vector<Passenger>`) and store pointers to dynamically allocated objects.
- Use a designated "null object" (the approach you describe).  Whether the "null object" is the default state of the object or an explicitly set state is up to you.
- Use a container of `struct { bool valid_; Passenger object_; };` as a crude "optional" type wrapper (this requires `Passenger` to be default constructible but does not require the default constructed object to be meaningful).
- Use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html#boost_optional.examples.optional_local_variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can have `null` in C++, provided you hold object pointers.

```
struct Passenger
{
    std::string name_;
};

std::string PassengerToString(const Passenger& p)
{
    return p.name_;
}


int main() 
{


    const int _totalSeats= 10;
    Passenger* Manifest[_totalSeats]  = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i< _totalSeats;i++)
    {
        if (Manifest[i] != 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"empty" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<< PassengerToString(*Manifest[i]) << std::endl;;
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

For real production code, you would use something like shared_ptr<>, but for an exercise in learning C++ post Java, doing this the low level way using raw pointers might be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you assistance

I was restricted in what data structures I was allowed to use
(I thought a map would have been a much better choice but they chose array....)

here is how I solved the problem in the end

as Friedman-hill so correctly mentioned when I dynamicly created my array it required a blank constructor of type Passenger to initalise.
I simply added a private data member bool "isEmpty" initalised to false to my consturctor.
then checked like so:

if (!Manifest[i].getIsEmpty())

thanks again